# You do not have permission to view this directory or page in Django app on Azure

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, azure, web-deployment-project

I am trying to deploy from my github repo a Django app. The deployment is successful, and when I check from the Azure command line, the files are there. However, when I access the website I get the following message:
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."
Can anyone help?

Comment: Not very easy to help with no information. Please edit your question with more concrete details.

Comment: Any update, @BeratBaranCevik?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Nope, but AWS worked fine